# Question about Javascript syntax in Codewars Kata

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am attempting to complete this Kata: https://www.codewars.com/kata/validate-sudoku-with-size-nxn/train/javascript. *Given a Sudoku data structure with size NxN, N > 0 and √N == integer, write a method to validate if it has been filled out correctly.*

They have given some wording to start off, some of which I don't understand. I believe I could solve this with just a normal function but some sections of what they have given are confusing me. Here is what they give to start with:

```js
var Sudoku = function(data) 
{
  //   Private methods
  // -------------------------



  //   Public methods
  // -------------------------
  return {
    isValid: function() {
      // YOUR SOLUTION

      return true;
    }
  };
};
```

In particular the lines below confuse me. Why do they mention private and public methods? And what is the isValid: function() about, is that just a new function called isValid within the Sudoku function? What is the purpose of doing that? Do I have to do it that way?

```
//   Private methods

//   Public methods

isValid: function() {
```

Answer (score 2):

> Why do they mention private and public methods?

A variable in a function isn't accessible outside that function.

Properties of an object returned from a function **are**.

> And what is the isValid: function() about, is that just a new function called isValid within the Sudoku function?

It's just standard [object initializer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) syntax.

`isValid` is the property name.

`function () { ... }` is a function expression which is the value assigned to that property.

> What is the purpose of doing that?

It lets you wrap up a bunch of functionality in a clear, easy to manage format while exposing an interface to it which is as simple as possible. This minimises the change of other code interfering with it as a side effect.

> Do I have to do it that way?

No.